# Redirect one viusalforce page to another page automatically using javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Can anyone tell me how to redirect one visualforce page to another visualforce page automatically ?
below is my visualforce page :

< apex:page standardController="Account"
contentType="application/msWord/#Test-{!NOW()}.doc"
   recordSetVar="accounts" sidebar="false"  cache="true">

```
<html xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
    <head>


    </head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <body>                       
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock title="Archiver For Account">
                 <div style="text-align:left" >          
                     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="ac" >
                         <apex:column headerValue="AccountName">
                             <apex:outputText >{!ac.Name}</apex:outputText>
                         </apex:column>
                         <apex:column headerValue="Account Number">
                             <apex:outputText >{!ac.AccountNumber}</apex:outputText>
                         </apex:column>
                         <apex:column headerValue="AccountType">
                             <apex:outputText >{!ac.Type}</apex:outputText>
                         </apex:column>
                         <apex:column headerValue="Phone Number">
                             <apex:outputText >{!ac.Phone}</apex:outputText>
                         </apex:column>                                       
                     </apex:pageBlockTable>  
                  </div>           
                </apex:pageBlock>

           <apex:outputText value="hi dude,"/>
       </apex:form>

    </body>
    <script>

        function redirect(){
            window.location.href='https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/AccountasTextfile'; 
        }

        window.onload = window.setTimeout(redirect(),5000);

    </script>
</html>
```

My question is once the document is downloaded then it will automatically redirect to another page as mentioned above.
I have tried using action attribute,calling redirect method from constructor. but nothing happen.
Finally I got the idea is using javascript we can redirect automatically.
but it dosent work for me.

Someone please tell me what I have to modify.

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using code given below in your first page :

```
PageReference OpenNewPage = Page.yoursecondpage;
OpenNewPage.setRedirect(false);
return OpenNewPage;
```

So that it won't redirect but download the word file. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code :

```
     <apex:commandButton value="openWindow"   onclick="window.open('https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/AccountasTextfile');"/>
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: Actually my problem is: I have two vfp. First page contain download button. If I click that  button then it will redirect to this page and download the content as word document.Once the doc is downloaded then it will automatically redirect to first page

Comment: For that What I have to do

Comment: So now your 2nd page doesn't redirect you to first page? Is it the problem?

Comment: Yeah. I don't know why it doesnt redirect automatically

Comment: Your problem seems similar to this one : [link]( http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5479/page-redirect-after-export-to-xl)

Comment: I have seen those links.  But I didnt get any idea to do this

Comment: Instead of using the html rendering you can try contentType="application/msWord" in your page and redirect from it.

Comment: Can you give the code snippet so that it will be beneficial for us

Comment: See my updated question